# Vba Code for Copying multiple cells and paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am started a Invoice with Vba. I have Code to copy a range of non empty cells and paste to another sheet and it is working perfectly but I want to copy some other cells and Paste them all in a row after the last used row.
Like 
"Invoice No, Date, Customer Name, Salesman Name and Total" as I can Used these to track Invoice.

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Dim x, y(), i As Long, ii As Long

    x = Sheets("Invoice").[a12:g49]
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
        If x(i, 1) <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve y(1 To 7, 1 To i)
            For ii = 1 To 7
                y(ii, i) = x(i, ii)
            Next
        Else: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    With Sheets("Invoice Record")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(y, 2), 7) = Application.Transpose(y)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what's the actual problem you're having? Do you have error? if so, what line raises the error? If not, please describe in more detail what the problem is, and consider providing some example data so that others can more easily recreate your problem. This is known as a [mcve], and it's part of [ask] a good question.

Comment: Above code is working only for range A12:G49 but I need code  that copy cells A3, A5, G3, G5 and G52 cells value also in a row